# Accessing parts of a json file

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file named region_descriptions.json which is available in the link http://visualgenome.org/static/data/dataset/region_descriptions.json.zip which I suggest that you download to understand the structure. Since this file is huge this doesn't properly open in most softwares(in my case google chrome did the trick for me). Inside this JSON file you will find many sentences as the value for the key "phrase". I need to write all the phrases(ONLY the phrases in SAME ORDER) in a different line in a .txt file.

I already got a .txt file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1unChUeCw6VTbSeHRppKJou6hsWm0Qdv4/view?usp=sharing) by running the following code

```
import json

with open("region_descriptions.json", 'r') as file:
    json_data = json.load(file)

f = open("text.txt","w")

for regions_dict in json_data:
    for region in regions_dict["regions"]:
        print(region["phrase"])
        f.write(region["phrase"]+"\n")
```

But I found out that some phrases have been printed more than twice in a row and there are empty lines in between which seems strange. I cannot open the json file to check that whether the .txt file I got is correct or not. Anyone with any solutions please?

Comment: Perhaps you meant `json_data["regions"]["phrase"]`?

Comment: I tried this out but I am getting a type error saying that list indices must be integers or slices, not str. I also printed the type of json_data to check and got <class 'list'> as output.

Comment: Note that the upvoted comment isn't the only problem and isn't a simple type-o, this question should be reopened.  The structure is more complex.

Comment: since it is closed, I'll try to jam the answer into the comments here

Comment: ```
import json

with open("region_descriptions.json", 'r') as file:
    json_data = json.load(file)

for regions_dict in json_data:
    for region in regions_dict["regions"]:
        print(region["phrase"])
```

Comment: @PraveenIyer try that

Comment: Yes I am sure it is not a simple typo and in my opinion can also be helpful for future visitors. So please reopen this question as soon as possible.

Comment: Hey @sniperd, I'm trying to reopen this question. Please post your answer there if it happens, thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much sniperd your code did work though I did not completely understand it. This code when run on different times will print all the sentences in the same order right or will the order vary?

Comment: Post a *small* sample of the JSON data into the question. If we have to download an external file to figure out what data you're working with, the question isn't self-contained enough.

Comment: Depending on your version of python, python 3.6+ will keep it in the same order.

Comment: Hey deceze I understand your point asking me to post a small sample of the json file but I would like to let you know the json file is too huge to post even a small sample that would help in my question. Posting a really small part would not help in this question and would lead to confusion.

Comment: Hey sniperd after running the code I saved all the phrases in a new line in a .txt file. But when I opened the .txt file at many places it seems a single phrases has been repeated more than thrice which is quiet strange and also there are some empty lines which means that the phrase string is empty. I am not even able to open the json file to check whether the .txt file I created is right or wrong. So any solutions for this strange problem? For reference I have added the link to the txt file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1unChUeCw6VTbSeHRppKJou6hsWm0Qdv4/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Also the code I used to get the .txt file has been updated in the question.

Comment: @PraveenIyer Glad we got the question back open!  I've written up an answer that should solve what you've got and get you going in the right direction.  If you find my answer helpful please upvote and accept it. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json 

with open("region_descriptions.json", 'r') as file:
    json_data = json.load(file) 

for regions_dict in json_data: 
    for region in regions_dict["regions"]: 
        print(region["phrase"])
```

This should do the trick.  It's is just a matter of quoting the keys you want and understanding the structure of the data.

Something helpful can be to do stuff like this:

```
import sys
import json
import pprint

with open("region_descriptions.json", 'r') as file:
    json_data = json.load(file)

for regions_dict in json_data:
    pprint.pprint(regions_dict["regions"])
    sys.exit()
```

And you'll get a nicely formatted output so you can better 'see' what the structure looks like.  It may be helpful to take a quick online course on `lists` and `dictionaries` to get an idea how these object hold data.  Basically `[ ]` is a list of data and `{ }` is a dictionary (key and value pairs).  Here is where I got started: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-python

The code should be working fine.  If there are dupe phrases that is because the `.json` has dupe phrases, and empty lines means some of the lines are empty.  If you'd like a unique list of phrases you can build off the existing code.  Something like add each phrase to a list if it doesn't exist in the list already.  Like this:

```
import sys
import json

with open("region_descriptions.json", 'r') as file:
    json_data = json.load(file)

phrase_list = []

for regions_dict in json_data:
    for region in regions_dict["regions"]:
        if region["phrase"] not in phrase_list:
            phrase_list.append(region["phrase"])
```

I would also suggest in the future if you can to use a small sample of data instead of a huge file.  Makes it easier to figure out what to do!  Good luck!

Comment: A well composed brilliant answer that helped me a lot. I upvoted the answer but it is not publicly visible since my reputation is less than 15 at the moment:(

Comment: @PraveenIyer happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you mean by "twice in a row." This solution works under the assumption that you are meaning "duplicate phrases."

```
import json

with open("region_descriptions.json", 'r') as file:
    json_data = json.load(file)

with open('test.txt','w') as f:


    all_phrases = []

    for regions_dict in json_data:
        for region in regions_dict["regions"]:
            all_phrases.append(region['phrase'])

    new_phrases = [phrase for phrase in all_phrases if phrase.strip()] #all non-empty phrases

    new_phrases_again = [phrase for i,phrase in enumerate(new_phrases) if phrase not in new_phrases[:i]] #if the phrase has not been used before in new_phrases, add it to the final list


    f.write("\n".join(new_phrases_again))
```

Sample test.txt output:

```
the clock is green in colour
shade is along the street 
man is wearing sneakers
cars headlights are off
bikes are parked at the far edge
A sign on the facade of the building
A tree trunk on the sidewalk
A man in a red shirt
A brick sidewalk beside the street
The back of a white car
```

Comment: Couldn't you work with sets instead of lists? So duplicates values can not happen, and thus you don't have to filter?

Comment: Sets will not return the items IN order if they appear more than once

Answer (score 0):

by the looks of the data it's a list of region dictionaries, who's value is a list of region dictionaries
CannedScientist beat me to the punch, doh!
[image]

my answer was going to look pretty similar, just without the last two list comprehensions
I was going to check for empty strings before appending.